# Flutter IOS in-app purchases initialization problem on IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase

I've just finished working on a personal app that has in-app purchases (Non-consumable). Unbelievably, the IAP part took me a lot of time due to a lack of documentation and complex testing process.

I am using the following package:
https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase

**Problem:**
If you reopen the app on IOS, the app doesn't initialize the purchases until you click the button to buy again. However, it works perfectly on Android.

```
Future<void> initializeIap() async {
    iapAvailable = await _iap.isAvailable();
    if (iapAvailable) {
      await _getProducts();
      await _getPastPurchases();
      _subscription = _iap.purchaseUpdatedStream.listen((data) {
        _purchases.addAll(data);
        _verifyPurchase();
      });
      _verifyPurchase();
    }
  }
```

```
Future<void> _getPastPurchases() async {
    QueryPurchaseDetailsResponse response = await _iap.queryPastPurchases();
    //TODO: IOS Complete Purchases
    for (PurchaseDetails purchase in response.pastPurchases) {
      if (Platform.isIOS) {
        InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.completePurchase(purchase);
      }
    }
    _purchases = response.pastPurchases;
  }
```

**TIP:**
Don't use 
`PurchaseStatus status;` to validate the state of the purchase.

Comment: I don't think the framework is designed to track purchases, only make them. You still need to set up your own system to track the purchase history/status for a user.

Comment: What if the user made a purchase, then requested a refund. The app will still work because of internal tracking.

Comment: Yup, you'll need to manage the purchase status server-side and listen for refunds if that's a requirement for your app - none of that is handled by the Flutter `in_app_purchase` package. There are hosted solutions out there (like [RevenueCat](https://github.com/RevenueCat/purchases-flutter)) that handle this for you.

Comment: @enc_life Thanks that useful for subscriptions. In my case is just a simple non-consumable product to remove ads from the app. I think you don't need any server to handle that.

Comment: Yeah, non-subscription simplifies things a lot but you will still need to track the status (is user premium or not) yourself.

Comment: @enc_life why can't I simply call the apple / google play API to check whether user purchased the goods/etc or not?

Comment: @atereshkov which API? Besides receipt validation there's no API on ios to get purchase history.

Comment: @enc_life what about this one? https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase#loading-previous-purchases (seems like you still can get non consumable purchases history)

Comment: @atereshkov I've never used that plugin but in the link you shared it says, "Note that the App Store does not have any APIs for querying consumable products, and Google Play considers consumable products to no longer be owned once they're marked as consumed and fails to return them here. For restoring these across devices you'll need to persist them on your own server and query that as well."

Comment: @enc_life Thanks, I've solved the problem by using RevenueCat on IOS only. There are a lot of issues in the official library for IOS.